# NFL blocked punt rules

Tags: rules, american-football

During the Giants vs Lions game on December 18th 2016 there was a punt partially blocked by the Lions. The ball was deflected after the punter kicked it by a Lions player. This resulted in the ball going forward but much shorter than the average punt. The ball was eventually blown dead by the referee as it had stopped moving and no player was picking it up.

My question is that if the Lions touched the ball after it was kicked why was it not just a live ball that the Giants could recover? If a Lions player touched the ball and didn't catch it the Giants could recover so why was this any different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question is that if the Lions touched the ball after it was kicked why was it not just a live ball that the Giants could recover? If a Lions player touched the ball and didn't catch it the Giants could recover so why was this any different?

It was different because partially blocking a kick is not considered touching the ball.

[Rule 9, Section 2, Article 2, Note 4](http://operations.nfl.com/the-rules/2016-nfl-rulebook/#article-2.-first-touching-beyond-the-line) in the 2016 NFL Rule Book states:

> A Team B (ie, Lions) player is deemed not to have touched a kick if such touching occurs in the immediate vicinity of the line in an attempt to block the kick.